# Parse String statement into a boolean expression

Tags: java

I have a string statement `String s = sb.contains("is");`

I want to use this in an `if` condition like

```
if (s) {
  //do something
}
```

How can I achieve this functionality?

Edit: Basically I get a boolean logic along with strings as an input. Ex: "Stack & over & (is | flow)". I have an array of sentences and I have to pick every sentence that follows this logic. I thought I would construct a string like "sb.contains(stack) && sb.contains(over) && (sb.contains(is) || sb.contains(flow))" and I thought I would run this boolean logic over all the sentences. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: `contains` returns a `boolean`. Is there a reason you're trying to store that result in a `String`?

Comment: Check edit for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The `contains` method returns a boolean value, so you can just simply set the type of variable 's' to a `boolean`.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String sb = "crisis";
        boolean s = sb.contains("is");
        
        if(s){
            System.out.println("S is true");
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)